# How to set Pycharm output path file by python

Tags: python, path, directory, save, pycharm

I write the code below to excel file but It have error

```
"C:\Users\InsiskyLee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe: can't open file 'Test': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

How to fix it? How to save file by specific path?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import time


book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

sheet['A1'] = 56
sheet['A2'] = 43

now = time.strftime("%x")
sheet['A3']=now

book.save("C:\\InsiskyLee\Desktop\TestWriteToExcel.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2):

You must put the path into a raw string because "\" is the escape character in python try

```
book.save(r"C:\InsiskyLee\Desktop\TestWriteToExcel.xlsx")
```

Comment: Still have same error : can't open file 'Test': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Comment: Show me how you defined the path to the file